# How do I enable a .jpg image to fade in, in swift uiKit

Tags: swift, uikit

Good evening.

I downloaded a .jpg image and attached it through storyboard, and linked it to Home.swift. At this point, when I run the simulator the image is there. It does nothing at this time, but it's there.

I am trying to modify the code so that the image fades in when the simulator first runs. However, swift isn't liking my approach.

Much appreciate any guidance.

```
import Foundation

import UIKit

class Home: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var lonelinessLbl: UILabel! 

    @IBOutlet var Image: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        startAnimations()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    }

    func startAnimations() {

        Image.animationImages = [

            UIImage(named: "birds.jpg")]

        Image.animationDuration = 3

        Image.startAnimations()   

    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `startAnimations`:

```
imageView.image = UIImage(named: "birds.jpg")
imageView.alpha = 0

UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 5.0, curve: .easeIn) {
  self.imageView.alpha = 1.0
}.startAnimation()
```

*(Note that I've renamed `Image` to `imageView` -- the Swift convention is to name variables in camel case, starting with a lowercase letter)*

Answer (score 1):

You can set the image to image view with animation.
Use the extension to apply animation anywhere.

```
extension UIImageView{
    func setAnimatedImage(_ image: UIImage?) {
        UIView.transition(with: self, duration: 0.5, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
            self.image = image
        }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Usage

```
yourImageView.setAnimatedImage(UIImage(named: "birds.jpg"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting an image array to animationImages only helps you when you have a set of images to animate it like a gif.

If you want to present animation like increasing alpha you can do the following.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    Image.alpha = 0.0
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3,
                   animations: {
                       self.Image.alpha = 1.0
                   },
                   completion: nil)
}
```